# Unable to find error in below code

Tags: pug

I am trying to display the users firstName and mobile number in a web page after he/she has successfully signed up. But while redirecting to that page, it is showing the below error :

> D:\myRobustApp\app\views\mydashboard.jade:5 3| block content 4| h1= title > 5| p Hi #{myuser.firstName} 6| p Your email is #{myuser.email} 7| p Your mobile number is #{myuser.mobileNumber} 8| p Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined

I have made a jade template file called "mydashboard.jade" with the below code:After successful signup user should be redirected to the above page and should be able to see his/her details.

```
extends mylayout

block content
  h1= title
  p Hi #{myuser.firstName}
  p Your email is #{myuser.email}
  p Your mobile number is #{myuser.mobileNumber}
  p
      a(href='http://localhost:3000/users/logout') logout
```

Can anyone help me in the issue?

Comment: Looks like `myuser` isn't defined, so you'll need to provide that data to your template.

Answer (score 1):

The user is undefined, so first check it.

```
extends mylayout

block content
  h1= title
  - if(typeof myuser !== 'undefined'){
  p Hi #{myuser.firstName}
  p Your email is #{myuser.email}
  p Your mobile number is #{myuser.mobileNumber}
  p
      a(href='http://localhost:3000/users/logout') logout              
  - } else {

  - }
```

Comment: I am still not able to display my web page